# Cognito: Facebook attributes not available in UI or ID Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

Yesterday, I setup a user-pool in Cognito w/ the Facebook Provider configured, allowing users of our iOS App to signup with Facebook. This has been implemented and the signup works perfectly.

The issue I am having is that Facebook attributes e.g. birthday, first_name, last_name, gender etc are not being synced into the Cognito user-pool. The attribute mappings are setup as per the screenshot below, and the client has been configured to read those attributes too. They are not visible in the UI, neither in the ID/access tokens being generated by Cognito.

When logging in via the iOS App, the "openid", "profile" and "email" scopes are requested. The Facebook identity provider has the following authorize scopes set: "email,public_profile,user_gender,user_birthday" so there shouldn't be any permission issues there.

Any ideas as to why these fields aren't being copied across? Name and email are visible, but the others are not.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you have your app approved by FB? They require their own review before you can request birthday or gender. Aside from that, Cognito seems to have trouble mapping these attributes, which is a similar problem I am looking to solve as well. Were you eventually able to get the mapping to work?